# How to alter a custom form

Tags: forms

I am using Drupal 7 to create an registration form, there are: username, email dan password fields, but I want to make an username checking while user leave username field (ajax).
I found an module as [Username Check](https://www.drupal.org/project/username_check)

This module is great and working in "myweb/user/register" form, but I need to move this function to my custom form in username field too

The code:

```
function username_check_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['username_check/isunique'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,  
    'page callback' => 'username_check_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'username_check.unique.inc',
  );

  $items['admin/config/system/username_check'] = array(
    'title' => 'Username check',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('username_check_settings'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'username_check.admin.inc',
  );

  return $items;
}

function username_check_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form) {

  $mode     = variable_get('username_check_mode', 'auto');

  if($mode != 'off') 
  {
    _username_check_load_resources($mode);
    $form['account']['name']['#field_suffix'] = '<span id="username-check-informer">&nbsp;</span>';
    $form['account']['name']['#suffix'] = '<div id="username-check-message"></div>';
  }

}

/**
 * Load username_check resources.
 */
function _username_check_load_resources($mode) {
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'username_check');
  drupal_add_css($module_path . '/username_check.css');
  drupal_add_js($module_path . '/username_check.js');

  drupal_add_js(array(
    'usernameCheck' => array(
      'ajaxUrl' => url('username_check/isunique', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
      'delay'   => variable_get('username_check_delay', 1),
    ),
  ), 'setting');
}
```

and my form as `userregis_form`
How to apply this to my custom form?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a validation to your form via

```
    $form['#validate'][] = 'yourFunction';


  function yourFunction($form, &$form_state) {
        //to show the form values
        dpm($form_state);
        //do validation
  }
```

Comment: im successfull to load the css file, but the ajax file not working. @user3278675 can you specify ur mean as #validate form?

Comment: im not talking about the module.

Im talking about making your own validation for the username.

Is there any configuration needed for it to work or did you just enabled it and it work on other form?